# Broadcast receiver at a specific Time

Tags: android

I want to create a broadcast receiver which will be invoking at the specific time say 9'o clock in morning.Is it possible in android,If yes Somebody please help me to do it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with any acceptable topic as described in the Help Center.

Comment: @ammukuttylive did you find the answer?