# How to send notification to perticular times in a day in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, notifications, logic

I have some records in my sqlite table,every record have time or timings,Now when reach that time in records, send alert notification to my mobile.
For ex: In my table 1-00,2-00,3-00,4-00 ... like that. When time reach 1-00, then send alert notification to me. How can i achieve this?

Comment: writing code would be a good start.

Comment: Hi Marc B, sorry for   with out code in my question,i don't know  how to start this task.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is an [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) with a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

E.g [take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429726/broadcastreceiver-and-alarmmanager-android)

Answer (score 1):

Google provide few examples here -> https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html.

You have to use the Class AlarmManager with few BroadcastReceivers (Time change and Boot completed).

BroadCastReceiver example -> [Broadcast receiver at a specific Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888773/broadcast-receiver-at-a-specific-time). (Using time as long, so you have to convert to long)